# Create New Word Document with Droplist Metadata

Tags: 2007, word, metadata

I have a new document library created in SharePoint 2007 and I have metadata associated with each entry.  These fields are mostly simple text fields. One such column is a drop-list that reads from another list in the same site collection. It works great within SharePoint. I have problems if I create a file via Word.

When I click New, Word 2007 opens and I can see the Document Properties from the server above the writing page. When I click the drop-list in question, I get a subset of my list.
I should see about 400 entries, but it ends after 100 entries. Is this a strict limitation or can it be edited?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I should have known this when the amount of entries was 100.  My issue was that the drop-list is reading from the default view for my list (Item limit 100). I modified the default view and then upped the Item limit to over 400.  I want back to click New.  All the entries are now in the drop-list.